# Adding Listeners to a Table

Tags: java, swing, mouse-listeners

I have a table with rows containing names of patients. I want to click on a name in the table and different attributes will display in box below depending on the patient clicked.

Here is what I've done so far. I don't know if what I've done is correct. In the GUI class where the table resides I have added listeners as shown. Needless to say it's not working. Could someone explain what needs to be done? Im confused with it all.

```
//Adding listeners for the table data.
void rowClickListener(MouseListener listenForMouseClickonRow)
 {
     table.addMouseListener( listenForMouseClickonRow);
     //table.getModel().addTableModelListener(listenForMouseClickonRow);
 }
```

Then in my controller class I have added a class it has forced me to add all these events which I dont even want:

```
public class rowClickListener implements MouseListener
{
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e) && e.getClickCount() == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("TEST mouse click");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe adding a `ListSelectionListener` to the table's model will work better, that way you can get the selected row number and then fetch the data from wherever you have it.

Comment: Yes, a ListSelectionListener is the way to go. This way the logic will also work when when the user uses the keyboard. Applications should be designed to work with the mouse or the keyboard. Advanced users use the keyboard, newbies use the mouse.

Answer (score 3):

```
    yourtable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            //your handle
        }
    }
```

I think that will work way better. With the `ListSelectionEvent` you can get the selected row.

Also, if only one record must be selected at a time, don't forget to set the selection mode of the table to `SINGLE_SELECTION`.